# Why PostgreSQL return different result for simular regexp?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm new in postgreSQL and facing a strange problem:

Queries return different results for the same regular expression. How it this possible?

And why do the first 3 queries return null when the last one returns the correct 'true'.

I read the [postgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) but still can't figure out where the difference is between those functions.

Please help.

```
select '12340599' like '^[0-9]*$'
select '12340599' similar to '^[0-9]*$'
select substring('12340599' from '^[0-9]*$' for '#')
select '12340599' ~ '^[0-9]*$'
```

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions. The first one does not contain any SQL wildcard so it's the same as `select '12340599' = '^[0-9]*$'`. `SIMILAR TO` does not support the full RegEx functionality if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is quite well written in the documentation. Each of those operators supports a specific pattern system:

**LIKE**

> If pattern does not contain percent signs or underscores, then the pattern only represents the string itself; in that case LIKE acts like the equals operator. An underscore (_) in pattern stands for (matches) any single character; a percent sign (%) matches any sequence of zero or more characters.

**SIMILAR TO**

> It is similar to LIKE, except that it interprets the pattern using the SQL standard's definition of a regular expression. SQL regular expressions are a curious cross between LIKE notation and common regular expression notation.

What exactly SQL regular expressions are can be found in [the same docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) you've already seen. These are a bit smaller then POSIX regular expressions. For example they don't support `^` and `$` special characters.

**~ operator**

These are [POSIX regular expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).

**substring**

See this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

If you use it with `FOR` it acts on SQL regular expressions. Without `FOR` it acts on POSIX regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing operators; have a deeper look at the documentation:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

---

> select '12340599' like '^[0-9]*$':

`LIKE` is not a regex operator, it uses `%` to match any string of zero or more characters and `_` for a single character match:

```
'abc' LIKE 'abc'    true
'abc' LIKE 'a%'     true
'abc' LIKE '_b_'    true
'abc' LIKE 'c'      false
```

---

> select '12340599' similar to '^[0-9]*$':

`SIMILAR TO` behave like the `LIKE` operator, but is also case insensitive.

---

> select substring('12340599' from '^[0-9]*$' for '#'):

You are using `substring(string from pattern for escape)` which extract substring matching SQL regular expression.

```
substring('Thomas' from '%#"o_a#"_' for '#') -> oma
```

---

*The regex operators are:*

```
~   Matches regular expression, case sensitive
~*  Matches regular expression, case insensitive
!~  Does not match regular expression, case sensitive
!~* Does not match regular expression, case insensitive
```